# Override JUnit 3 Test Method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have some common classes which all need to run the same unit tests, however for some of the classes the expected results of some of the tests are different.

**Ex. For Test1**

- Class 1 Expected Result is 1
- Class 2 Expected Result is 1
- Class 3 Expected Result is 2

My idea was to have a common set of tests in one class and have each class I needed to test extend this test suite. The extended version of the test class could then override the test methods in which a different result is expected. The issue is that when I do this the overriden version of the method is never called. Is there a way that I can make this work?

```
public class BaseTest extends TestCase{

    ClassToBeTested classInstance = new ClassToBeTested()

    public void testOne(){
       // Testing logic here on classInstance
    }
} 

public class ClassToBeTested2Test extends BaseTest {

    ClassToBeTested2 class2Instance = new ClassToBeTested2()

    @Override
    public void testOne(){
       // Testing logic here on class2Instance
       // This is never run
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be annotating the methods with `@Test` nor do you seem to be extending from `TestCase`. Are these classes the actual JUnit test classes?

Comment: BaseTest does extend TestCase(just updated post to show that). Junit 3 does not have the @Test annotation, it just looks for methods that start with test

Comment: Yes I am aware of @Test not being available but you didn't seem to be extending rom `TestCase` earlier.  How are you running these tests?

Comment: I'm just running them using a Junit test runner in intelliJ

Comment: How dd you validate that the overriden method is never called?